# where exaclty ports should be implemented?

Tags: event-handling, domain-driven-design, hexagonal-architecture

In DDD implementation with Hexagonal Architecture the application might have ports (interfaces) and adapters (clients) .In my current project I am implementing Event driven based micorservices .I have a domain application service layer and and infrastructure layer and adapter layer (for commands listeners).
I have googled many implementation and infrastructure layer contains the adapters as well as ports .
now the infrastructure layer once will invoke the application service layer which is wrong as per my understating .

Is this correct implementation .where to add the the ports/command listeners.

Answer (score 3):

I do the following matching between DDD layers and hexagonal architecture:

- The driver ports are the DDD application services interfaces, they are the left edges of the hexagon.
- The inside of the hexagon is divided into the DDD application services implementation and the DDD domain model.
- The driven ports (for example a repository interface, or a  service interface that is implemented by infrastructure), are the right edges of the hexagon.
- The inside of the hexagon implements the driver ports and use the driven ports.
- A driver adapter (for example, a REST API  controller, or a web app) uses/calls a driver port. The drivers adapters are the presentation layer of DDD.
- A driven adapter implements a driven port. Driven adapters are the infrastructure layer of DDD.

If you want to take a look, here's an article I wrote explaining hexagonal architecture:

https://softwarecampament.wordpress.com/portsadapters

Hope it helps.